# Creating and then mergint two completely unrelated git branches

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm creating a react app, and for the next step (pun intended) I'd like to migrate that project to next.js if I'm able to do so. I have done 10/12 commits of my react app  to my master branch.

Would it be doable to create a new branch and start a next.js project from scratch and then slowly migrate one project into the other?

I understand that the sensible thing to do would be creating two different repos but since this is for a job application assignment, in which react is required and next.js desired, It would be necessary to make it in just one repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not. Git does not care which content do you keep in repository - so you could have in one repository source code done in different languages/for different purposes. The question is whether it is logical - but in your case it is, because both parts relate to one project. Simply create branch from `master`, implement there your `next.js` part, and then merge it with `master` branch back.